NextJS 14 & SupabaseAuth, SupabasePostgres
Firstly I am a Full Stack Bootcamp Graduate and just trying to get my head into NextJS, so this might be newbie questions here.
Now I am using a NextJS TypeScript template and using Supabase for authentication:

Using Supabase, I want to store the signup (during/after user creation) formdata (especially userrole & callsign, but also firstname und lastname) directly to the db in the users table and not in the session or raw_user_meta_data. Is this possible via supabase? I have already added two new columns to the auth.users table in via SQL editor in the supabase account. So once a user signs up the first time, his form data should be stored in the auth.user table.

Some code here:
sign-up-form.tsx
 import ....

const schema = zod.object({
  firstname: zod.string().min(3, { message: 'First name is required' }),
  lastname: zod.string().min(3, { message: 'Last name is required' }),
  email: zod.string().min(3, { message: 'Email is required' }).email(),
  callsign: zod.string().min(3, { message: 'CallSign is required' }),
  userrole: zod.string().min(3, { message: 'Userrole is required' }),
  password: zod.string().min(6, { message: 'Password should be at least 6 characters' }),
  terms: zod.boolean().refine((value) => value, 'You must accept the terms and conditions'),
});

 const onSubmit = React.useCallback(
    async (values: Values): Promise<void> => {
      setIsPending(true);

      const redirectToUrl = new URL(paths.auth.supabase.callback.pkce, window.location.origin);
      redirectToUrl.searchParams.set('next', paths.dashboard.overview);

const defaultValues = { firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '', callsign:'', userrole: '', password: '', terms: false } satisfies Values;

const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.signUp({
        // firstName: values.firstName, // VS code error msg "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'firstName' does not exist in type SignUpWithPasswordCredentials'.",
        // lastName: values.lastName, // VS code error here too
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        options: {
          data: {
            callsign: values.callsign, // this will be available in raw_metadata but I directly want to save it to the db in auth.users
            userrole: values.userrole, //save this in the db too
          },
          emailRedirectTo: redirectToUrl.href,
        },
      });
if (error) {
        setError('root', { type: 'server', message: error.message });
        setIsPending(false);
        return;
      }

      if (data.session) {
        return;
      }

      if (data.user) {
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams({ email: values.email });
        router.push(`${paths.auth.supabase.signUpConfirm}?${searchParams.toString()}`);
        return;
      }

      setIsPending(false);
    },
    [supabaseClient, router, setError]
  );


return(
Form....
......

signUp function (GoTrueClients.ts)
async signUp(credentials: SignUpWithPasswordCredentials): Promise<AuthResponse> {
    try {
      await this._removeSession()

      let res: AuthResponse
      if ('email' in credentials) {
        const { email, password, options } = credentials
        let codeChallenge: string | null = null
        let codeChallengeMethod: string | null = null
        if (this.flowType === 'pkce') {
          const codeVerifier = generatePKCEVerifier()
          await setItemAsync(this.storage, `${this.storageKey}-code-verifier`, codeVerifier)
          codeChallenge = await generatePKCEChallenge(codeVerifier)
          codeChallengeMethod = codeVerifier === codeChallenge ? 'plain' : 's256'
        }
        res = await _request(this.fetch, 'POST', `${this.url}/signup`, {
          headers: this.headers,
          redirectTo: options?.emailRedirectTo,
          body: {
            email,
            password,
            data: options?.data ?? {},
            gotrue_meta_security: { captcha_token: options?.captchaToken },
            code_challenge: codeChallenge,
            code_challenge_method: codeChallengeMethod,
          },
          xform: _sessionResponse,
        })
      } else if ('phone' in credentials) {
        const { phone, password, options } = credentials
        res = await _request(this.fetch, 'POST', `${this.url}/signup`, {
          headers: this.headers,
          body: {
            phone,
            password,
            data: options?.data ?? {},
            channel: options?.channel ?? 'sms',
            gotrue_meta_security: { captcha_token: options?.captchaToken },
          },
          xform: _sessionResponse,
        })
      } else {
        throw new AuthInvalidCredentialsError(
          'You must provide either an email or phone number and a password'
        )
      }

      const { data, error } = res

      if (error || !data) {
        return { data: { user: null, session: null }, error: error }
      }

      const session: Session | null = data.session
      const user: User | null = data.user

      if (data.session) {
        await this._saveSession(data.session)
        await this._notifyAllSubscribers('SIGNED_IN', session)
      }

      return { data: { user, session }, error: null }
    } catch (error) {
      if (isAuthError(error)) {
        return { data: { user: null, session: null }, error }
      }

      throw error
    }
  }

middleware.tsx:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import { config as appConfig } from '@/config';
import { AuthStrategy } from '@/lib/auth/strategy';
import { supabaseMiddleware } from '@/lib/auth/supabase/middleware';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest): Promise<NextResponse> {
  let res: NextResponse;

  if (appConfig.auth.strategy === AuthStrategy.SUPABASE) {
    res = await supabaseMiddleware(req);
  } else {
    res = NextResponse.next({ headers: req.headers });
  }

  return res;
}

export const config = { matcher: ['/auth/:path*', '/dashboard/:path*'] };

2. After a login I want to fetch the userrole from db from auth.users to then conditional render multiple dashboards depending on the fetched userrole from auth.users.
According to the supabase docu (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select) this should work:
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('countries')
  .select()

but it doesn't as modules and other functions are missing.
Sorry...quite junior noob questions I guess. Thanks already
Just mentioned above what I tried and pasted some code snippets.
Maybe you have some recommendations of additional documentation or example github repos that i can look into?
What am I missing?


I want to store the signup (during/after user creation) formdata (especially userrole & callsign, but also firstname und lastname) directly to the db in the users table and not in the session or raw_user_meta_data. Is this possible via supabase?

One approach for this after log-in you have a separate form for the users data like first_name .... and you store it in a separate profiles table where the user_id is a foreign key. Something similar to this example here https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/tutorials/with-nextjs?queryGroups=language&language=js#account-page


After a login I want to fetch the userrole from db from auth.users to then conditional render multiple dashboards depending on the fetched userrole from auth.users.


For this you can query the user_role from the profiles table like this
const {data, error} = await supabase.from("profiles").select("user_role")

based on this you can perform your conditional render.
NOTE: In order for the above query to work you need to update your Row level policy (RLS) for the table, if not you will get empty data.
Hope this helps
